# openX Ad server not displaying the banner image

Tags: linux, openx

openX ad server not displaying the banner image. It showing white box only.
version-openx.2.8.10 with plugins.
os - ubuntu 12.04

How do i set up banner to show up the image. 
when i use [path](http://www.example.com/openx/www/images/xyxyx.gif).

Its displaying the ad image. 
In banner properties i could'nt view the image. its just showing white box.

Help me. i struggling for 2 day to solve the issue.i not getting any clue. how can i solve the issue. Thanks. Waiting for reply.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a few years late to the party, but I had a similar issue with displaying an image openx.png.  I changed the name to open.png and it worked fine.

try changing the path from:
http://www.example.com/openx/www/images/xyxyx.gif
to
http://www.example.com/open/www/images/xyxyx.gif